# Error while saving MetadataServiceImported class

Tags: apex, metadata-api, wsdl2apex, financialforce

[image]

Trying to generate a MetadataService class using the instructions on the github repo of financial force, the MetadataServiceImported class generated from the WSDL is not getting saved and it says Script too long.

So I tried to copy the generated code and create a new apex class in the developer console, and it still doesn't save and it says STRING_TOO_LONG, as you can see in the screenshot.

The generated MetadataServiceImported Class has 1552574 characters.

[financial force github repo](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

Comment: So maybe you could state in your question how many characters your class code actually has?! I'd not be extremely surprised, if the amount of generated code were actually a problem.

Comment: OK @FelixvanHove , I just added the character count.